# How to display http icon in https in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have hosted my silverlight application on one server in https mode. my images are in server and it's url is as http://localhost/icons/3g.png

My application runs on https site and its is unable to load these image file in silverlight application.

Thanks for your help and support.

Please reply ASAP.

Comment: you need to change "Localhost" with actual name of your image server or IP.

Comment: i have changed it to ip. i am still unable to access those url from https hosted site.

Comment: Now you have to post your Code, Else I can't guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the image url as follows?
http://localhost/icons/3g.png

Use the relative path instead of the absolute path.